# SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField - Show both date and time for input

Tags: page-layout, branding

I am working with my page layout and I have the following tag ...

```
<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField FieldName="Article Date" runat="server" id="DateTimeField1" />
```

The only problem I have is I want the user to not only pick the date, but the time as well nd I have no idea how to set that property.

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow select Date and Time in [DateTimeField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.datetimefield.aspx) control, specify for [Date and Time field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielddatetime.aspx) the Date & Time [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spdatetimefieldformattype.aspx)

[image]

In your case for field `Article Date` format should be changed to `Date & Time`

---

### DateOnly and TimeOnly properties of DateTimeField control

First of all, DateOnly and TimeOnly properties of [DateTimeField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.datetimefield.aspx) control is not about specifying format of stored field values, but only indicates whether the control displays time values and(or) date values

> Actually, specifying DateOnly and TimeOnly properties explicitly cause
>   this error:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object.     at
>   SharePoint.ControlExtender.WebControls.DateTimeField.set_DateOnly(Boolean
>   value)      at T_DateTimeField_DateOnly_11.SetProperty(Object , Object
>   )      at System.Web.Util.FastPropertyAccessor.SetProperty(Object
>   target, String propName, Object val, Boolean inDesigner)      at
>   System.Web.UI.PropertyMapper.SetMappedPropertyValue(Object obj, String
>   mappedName, Object value, Boolean inDesigner)      at
>   System.Web.UI.ControlBuilder.SetSimpleProperty(SimplePropertyEntry
>   entry, Object obj)

Article Date field is OOTB page field and declared like this ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648024.aspx)):

```
<Field ID="{71316CEA-40A0-49f3-8659-F0CEFDBDBD4F}" 
       Name="ArticleStartDate" 
       StaticName="ArticleStartDate" 
       SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" 
       Group="$Resources:cmscore,group_publishingcolumns;" 
       DisplayName="$Resources:cmscore,column_articlestartdate_displayname;" 
       Type="DateTime" 
       Format="DateOnly" 
       Required="FALSE" 
       Sealed="TRUE" 
       StorageTZ="UTC">
</Field>
```

So, OOTB Article Date field is supported to store **Dates** only.

It is not recommended  to change OOBT fields, the following solution demonstrates  how to display Article Date with Date & Time format

### How to display Article Date using Date & Time format

1. Create custom Article Date field of Date & Time type and with **Date & Time format**
2. Add this field to Content Type associated with Page Layout
3. Add control declaration to page layout:    `<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField FieldName="Custom Article Date and Time" runat="server" />`

Comment: Ok, that column ('Article Date') is one of the publishing columns so it is out of the box and not editable. But in checking it says 

'The type of information in this column is: Date and Time'

So ... why is it not showing the time as well?

Comment: OK so then I tried changing the SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField to SharePointWebControls:DateTimeControl for Date and Time and got this error ... Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DateTimeControl' does not have a public property named 'FieldName'. I am lost

Comment: The answer has been updated, basically, the recommendation is to create custom Article Date field with Date & Time format

Comment: Thanks Vadim, I was hoping it did not have to do that but with your great explanation I now know this is the right way to proceed. Thanks so much - Mike

Answer (score 0):

Not certain but you could try setting DateOnly="false".

Comment: Tried that, but then my pages started throwing errors.

Comment: DateOnly is one of the most hideous properties. It will almost always throw errors in display mode