# SharePointWebControls FieldValue Yes/No

Tags: spfield

Wondering if you could help me please. Currently have a page layout with a SharePointWebControl inserted on the page:

```
<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Boolean1" runat="server" />
```

The field itself is a SharePoint **"Yes/No"** field and currently displays "yes" or "no", however I want to get the value as **"true"**, **"false"**, **"1"** or **"0"**

Just wondering if anyone knows of a way of doing this please.

Comment: Have you tried `SharePointWebControls:BooleanField` instead of `SharePointWebControls:FieldValue`

Answer (score 1):

You should set the control as follow:

```
MyCustomField.ItemFieldValue = "1";
MyCustomField.Field.DefaultValue = "1";
```

Where 1 is for true, and 0 is for false

**ASPX**

```
<SharePoint:BooleanField runat="server" FieldName="boolField" ControlMode="New" ID="MyCustomField"/>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
if (!SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin) // For example
{
 MyCustomField.Value = true; // Visually no changes
 MyCustomField.UpdateFieldValueInItem(); // Still nothing
}
```

**For Reference:** https://www.schaeflein.net/enhanced-booleanfield-control-for-sharepoint-publishing/

**Helpful link:** For Good Answer [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67206/sharepointwebcontrolsdatetimefield-show-both-date-and-time-for-input)